# Ubuntu 20.04 takes 30s and 15s before shutdown and booting actually starts

Tags: boot, 20.04, shutdown

I upgraded from 18.04 to 20.04, and also have the latest OS updates.

**Problem:** Even when I have no foreground applications nor any heavyduty services running, it takes a consistent 30 seconds after I've selected and confirmed "Shutdown" for the shutdown sequence to actually begin.

Likewise, when I reboot, after the Dell logo is done flashing, it takes a consistent 15 seconds for the Ubuntu related bootup messages so start showing up.

I faced no such issue in Ubuntu 18.04.

I suspect this could be due to my choosing to upgrade; a fresh install of 20.04 was/is not an option.

**UPDATE on the shutdown part**

Right after `15:30:00` I confirm the shutdown via Unity GUI. Notice the large gap between `15:30:04` and `15:30:28`. This is the '30 second' delay that I'm experiencing every time during shutdown. By `15:30:34` the entire shutdown is complete.

What should I look into next?

```
Mar 15 15:28:59 dart unity-panel-ser[2698]: menus_destroyed: assertion 'IS_WINDOW_MENU(wm)' failed
Mar 15 15:30:01 dart CRON[6019]: (root) CMD ([ -x /etc/init.d/anacron ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d anacron start >/dev/null; fi)
Mar 15 15:30:04 dart unity-panel-ser[2698]: menus_destroyed: assertion 'IS_WINDOW_MENU(wm)' failed
Mar 15 15:30:04 dart gnome-session[2557]: gnome-session-binary[2557]: WARNING: Failed to get delay inhibitor: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.login1.OperationInProgress: The operation inhibition has been requested for is already running
Mar 15 15:30:04 dart gnome-session-binary[2557]: WARNING: Failed to get delay inhibitor: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.login1.OperationInProgress: The operation inhibition has been requested for is already running
Mar 15 15:30:04 dart gnome-session-binary[2557]: Entering running state
Mar 15 15:30:04 dart unity-panel-ser[2698]: Getting layout failed: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownObject: No such object path '/MenuBar/1'
Mar 15 15:30:04 dart systemd[1]: unattended-upgrades.service: Succeeded.
Mar 15 15:30:28 dart wpa_supplicant[915]: wlp1s0: CTRL-EVENT-BEACON-LOSS 
Mar 15 15:30:28 dart whoopsie[2125]: [15:30:28] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Mar 15 15:30:28 dart whoopsie[2125]: [15:30:28] offline
Mar 15 15:30:28 dart whoopsie[2125]: [15:30:28] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
```

Comment: I have seen my system pause for an inordinate amount of time while waiting for the snap daemon to shutdown - this can be detected during the shutdown process if you have disabled the "quiet splash" in grub.  [This article](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2019/12/slow-shutdown-stop-job-running/) describes one method of dealing with this.

Comment: Check /var/log/syslog for error messages (or "wating for..." messages) during boot and shutdown.

Comment: Chances are good that you will not have the issue if you do a *fresh* install of the newer Ubuntu, i.e., erasing the existing system. With an upgrade, there is quite some chance to have some issues, like this. Not sure why a fresh install is not an option.

Comment: @user535733 I added an Update section.

Comment: @CharlesGreen I'd already set that flag to `4s` (instead of the original `90s`). It made no difference, which is why I posted here.

Comment: Looks like the delay is a *symptom* caused by some process or application crashing earlier during shutdown. Whoopsie/Daisy (15:30:28) is the crash-reporting process that sends the crash report to Canonical. The 30-second delay looks like it occurs when Whoopsie is trying to access the network (which is already down, hence the delay and failure). Look slightly earlier in your log to figure out what is crashing during shutdown and why. Also look in /var/crash for a .crash file matching the shutdown time -- the creation of that crash file is what triggers Whoopsie.